# Word count program in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm going over past exams studying for my upcoming exam, and after completing a couple of the questions I came across one that I couldn't solve.

It wants a function that will take a String (or [Char]) and return an Int of the number of english words that are in the String.  It says that isWord is a hypothetical function that takes a String and returns a Boolean depending on if the word is true or false.
The words must be in a row, left to right.  The example given was "catalogre". So "cat", "at", "catalog", "ogre" and "log", the function should return 5.

```
wordsInString :: [Char] -> Int
wordsInString [] = 0
wordsInString x
    | isWord (take 1 x)
    | isWord (take 2 x)
```

The bumpers are just showing what I was thinking, obviously it wont work.

This is how I started, and I was thinking that I could use the `take` function and increment it each letter at a time, then move the starting letter down until `[]`, but I wasn't sure how to implement that recursion correctly. If anyone has any ideas or could show me a way, it would be great.

Answer (score 7):

If you know how to distinguish word from non-word you can use [`inits`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3ainits) and [`tails`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.5.0.0/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3atails) to get list of all possible candidates:

```
> :m +Data.List
> concatMap inits $ tails "catalogre"
["","c","ca","cat","cata","catal","catalo","catalog","catalogr","catalogre","","a","at","ata","atal","atalo","atalog","atalogr","atalogre","","t","ta","tal","talo","talog","talogr","talogre","","a","al","alo","alog","alogr","alogre","","l","lo","log","logr","logre","","o","og","ogr","ogre","","g","gr","gre","","r","re","","e",""]
```

Comment: Perhaps in conjunction with `nub`, depending on whether both "an"s in "banana" should be counted.

Comment: `$ :: (a -> b) -> a -> b` is right-associative function application: `f $ g $ h x  =  f (g (h x))`

Comment: `concatMap` is `concat` applied to the results of `map`: `concatMap f xs = concat $ map f xs`

Comment: Ooh, and you can golf this to `inits <=< tails`

Answer (score 4):

That problem statement is a little vague. I'm going to make a couple assumptions that aren't explicitly stated - a word can be a prefix of another word, and that duplicate words count each time.

Then, to approach solving a problem like this, break it down into parts. You've already done a little of this, but you seem to have not followed up on it code. A strong feature of Haskell is that your code structure will often follow the structure of your thoughts.

So, you have clearly decided you want to generate all the appropriate substrings to test, then count the results. Let's start by putting that into code.

```
wordCount :: String -> Int
wordCount = length . findWords

findWords :: String -> [String]
findWords = filter isWord . makeSubstrings

makeSubstrings :: String -> [String]
makeSubstrings xs = undefined -- hmm, this isn't clear yet
```

Ok. That's a starting point. It gets down to the heart of the problem. How are you going to come up with all the candidate substrings to test?

Well, your question already shows the necessary ideas. Just decompose them into pieces small enough you can see how to do them. You mentioned wanting to do something from every starting position in the string. So how about writing a function that returns the strings starting from each position, and going to the end? That seems like a logical first step.

```
-- for the input "foo", this should return the list ["foo", "oo", "o", ""]
tails :: String -> [String]
tails = undefined -- I'll leave this one up to you
```

That choice of name isn't arbitrary.  There's a function that does exactly this in `Data.List` already, but you should implement it yourself, just to see how it's done.

But you clearly also saw that you need to look at all the prefixes of those, with your idea to take pieces. So, write another function to generate all the prefixes of a string. This also exists in `Data.List` as `inits`, but again, try writing it yourself.

```
-- for the input "foo", this should return the list ["", "f", "fo", "foo"]
inits :: String -> [String]
inits = undefined - again, this is up to you
```

And, with `map` and `concat`, these add up to the pieces you need to implement `makeSubstrings`, as the other answers show. Hopefully, I was able to actually convey a sense of how to reason about the steps necessary, and how to use those steps to structure your code.

Answer (score 2):

<s>You are looking for the [`subsequences`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3asubsequences) function from Data.List.</s>

It it a good idea to read through [the libraries that come with GHC](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/index.html), especially base. Even if you are not allowed to use these functions in the exam, it is still useful and sometimes enlightening to read the source code (follow the “Source” link to the right of the type signature).

---

Edit: the comments are right, and so is Matvey's answer. You can unaccept my answer and accept Matvey's instead.

Comment: I also thought so, but subsequences are not necessarily consecutive, and he only needs consecutive subsequences.

Comment: This isn't `subsequences` - it needs consecutive subsequences only.

Comment: Take `subsequences "hhi"`, e.g. Among the others, you'll have two results for `"hi"` (one with the first occurrence of h, one with the second), and you end up counting two words instead of only one.

Comment: basically what I need, except `subsequences "abc"` will return things like `"ac"` which are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

```
allWordsInString :: [Char] -> [[Char]]
allWordsInString = filter isWord . concat . map tails . inits
--                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ or, concatMap tails

wordsInString :: [Char] -> Int
wordsInString = length . allWordsInString
```

I would suggest something like this, because it could be interesting to also know which are the english words in your given string.

`(.)` is function composition. `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]` flattens a list, e.g. `concat [[1,2], [], [3] == [1,2,3]`. `inits` returns all possible initial prefixes of a given list, `tails` the same for suffixes. `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` finally takes a predicate, a list, and returns a list containing only the elements that satisfy the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which doesn't use any fancy Haskell features other than concatenating lists, computing the length of a list, taking the tail of a list - and recursion.

The idea is this:

1. First write a function `candidatesWithLength :: Int -> String -> [String]` which is given an item length and some string, and then yields a list with all items of that length, so that it behaves like this:

   ```
   > candidatesWithLength 3 "Foo"
   ["Foo"]
   > candidatesWithLength 2 "Foo"
   ["Fo", "oo"]
   > candidatesWithLength 1 "Foo"
   ["F", "o", "o"]
   ```
2. Then, using the above `candidatesWithLength` function, write a function `candidates :: String -> [String]` which yields all "candidates" (potential words) for a given string. The function simply builds a long list with all candidates of length 1 plug the candidates of length 2, plus those of length 3 and so on. It behaves like this:

   ```
   > candidates "Foo"
   ["Foo", "Fo", "oo", "F, "o", "o"]
   ```
3. If you have this, you coud use the existing [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3afilter) function on the returned list so that you skip all the things for which your given `isWord` function yields false, like this:

   ```
   > filter isWord (candidates "catalogre")
   ["catalog", "ogre", "cat", "log", "at"]
   ```

Here's an implementation of the two methods `candidatesWithLength` and `candidates` which does not use too many fancy features:

```
candidatesWithLength :: Int -> String -> [String]
candidatesWithLength len s
    | len > (length s) = []
    | otherwise        = go s (length s - len + 1)
    where go _ 0 = []
          go s' movesLeft = take len s' : go (tail s') (movesLeft - 1)

candidates :: String -> [String]
candidates s = go (length s)
    where go 0 = []
          go itemLength = candidatesWithLength itemLength s ++ go (itemLength - 1)
```